# Installation of Windows XP SP2 using a bootable USB on a tablet

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I bought an second hand tablet. Fortunately the drivers are still available but only for Windows XP SP2. I have to install Windows XP SP2 in it but I don't have a CD-ROM so I need to make my USB bootable. Unfortunately everytime I burn the image on my USB using RUFUS 2.2, the setup couldn't find EULA agreement (which was present in the image). Then I used a suggestion to change the ID to 0x80 and the setup picked up the EULA agreement and installed the windows but when I restarted my tablet it gave me this error:
"system32\hal.dll missing or corrupt reinstall"
Then I followed the steps provided in this link:

http://ccm.net/forum/affich-109031-window-root-system32-missing-or-corrupt

And It still didn't work.

My question is it even possible to install Windows XP SP2 on a tablet using a bootable USB? If so can you tell me the steps or suggest a link ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [See this article](http://www.oxhow.com/install-windows-xp-from-usb-flash-pen-drive/)

Comment: [Also see this one](http://agnipulse.com/2010/04/rmprepusb-amazing-usb-formatting-tool/)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Moab! Your link led me to this one right here:

http://www.oxhow.com/install-windows-xp-usb-drive-part-2/

And it worked! Except it needs you to have:

1. Windows xp already installed in the pc from which you'll burn your image on your usb
2. Usb of small size < 4GB but I think a newer version of PeToUSB allows that feature
3. A Windows XP SP2 CD. I don't know if a download using torrent works as well.